# Incomplete data upload to SQL server using perl script

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

I have a script that reads a two column CSV I generate based on the current library of files I am accessing. I chomp the file into an array, then I upload the CSV element by element to an SQL table using the code below:

```
    my $e_sth = $trans->prepare("delete from $table where 1 = 1");
    $e_sth->execute();

    my $u_sql = qq{
            insert into $table (KTM, SUBSITE) values
                        (?, ?)
        };
    my $u_sth = $trans->prepare($u_sql);

    foreach my $rec (@list) {
        my ($klf, $subsite) = split(",", $rec);

        # Upload
        $u_sth->execute($klf, $subsite)
    }

    $trans->commit();
```

It is always the last line of the file, so I'm sure that will key some of you off right away to the issue. I am lost though. I assumed the `foreach` loop would prevent something like this from happening. The amount of characters from the last line being truncated varies as well. Both columns are set up as CHAR(100) with the KTM column being the primary key.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: It looks like I might be reaching some sort of data limit for the table. I'll look into expanding the allocated size of the table.

Comment: Maybe it's not related, but there's no need to the `WHERE` clause there (`where 1 = 1`), unless you're deleting some specific rows.

Comment: Your DBI-code looks correct, start debugging, by adding some "logging" . E.g. changing `$u_sth->execute($klf, $subsite)` to `warn "$klf -> $subsite"; warn $u_sth->execute($klf, $subsite)` and a look in the error-log might help.